# What rounding method should you use in Java for money?

Tags: java, rounding, currency

Suppose I have a decimal value in Java that represents money.

What's the best way to round these values?

For example, if I have a value that's calculated based on a tax rate and I end up with a result of, say, `5.3999999999999995` as the tax amount, should I round it to 2 decimal places simply by doing this:

```
double d = 5.3999999999999995
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(d).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
d = bd.doubleValue();
```

to produce the currency value:

```
5.40
```

Comment: The exact formula used to round values is typically specified in a contract that has some legal authority. Nevertheless, you should *never* use `double`s to represent amounts of money.

Comment: I see. Why should you not use `double`s? `Float`s are better? I thought it's better to have more precision rather than less - and therefore to use `double`s as much as possible. But I'm happy to be corrected.

Comment: float is not the way to go either

Comment: @Woot4Moo: Any particular reason?

Comment: @Tom float is inherently inaccurate. this article may be of help. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/125056   the basic gist is a computer doesn't know how to represent a fraction of an integer.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Didn't know that. Good thing I found this out in time.

Comment: Rounding rules are also currency-specific.

Comment: @Tom: No, binary floats are absolutely not meant or fit to be used for money. They were designed mainly for numerical application (engineering and science). Read more here: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: @Woot4Moo: computers can represent fractions just fine, and floats do exactly that. Problems only appear when people expect the behaviour of decimal fractions while using a binary format. Nobody is suprised when there's problems representing 1/3 exactly.

Answer (score 7):

Most applications that calculate money don't use floating point (`double`, `float`); they use integer amounts representing a smaller unit.  For example in $USD, money can be represented in *pennies* which is 1/100 of a dollar.

For better accuracy, you may want to have an integer represent 1E-03 ("milli-dollars") or 1E-06.  This depends on issues such as interest calculations and your level of precision.

Comment: Is it bad to use floating point for money? I thought that's exactly what floating point is for? Feel free to correct me - I really don't know.

Comment: yes, it's bad to use floating point for money.  No, floating point numbers were not developed to represent money.  I think scientific computing had far more to do with it.

Comment: Floating points give you 3.4444444444 dollars, hard to cash that

Comment: +1 for not using float or double for currency.  Much better to use an integer and think of dollars as cents instead.

Comment: Integers are only a nasty hack for when you don't have something like BigDecimal - which Tom is ironically already using, just not completely.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @Laurent Pireyn that you should round according to the contract. For example, the [IRS](http://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040nre/ch02.html) has you round to the nearest dollar. They say

> You can round off cents to whole
>   dollars on your return. If you do
>   round to whole dollars, you must round
>   all amounts. To round, drop amounts
>   under 50 cents and increase amounts
>   from 50 to 99 cents to the next
>   dollar. For example, $1.39 becomes $1
>   and $2.50 becomes $3

Nice use of `RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN`. That eliminates the need for you to write and test an function.

If this actually is a tax rate for the IRS, I think that `RoundingMode.HALF_UP` would be correct.

Answer (score 2):

Money is usually rounded using the "round half to even" rule (also called "banker's rounding). It says that ties are broken by choosing the closest **even** digit. This can be shown to eliminate bias in rounding for both positive and negative values. (It's not the only rounding rule that has this property, but it's a nice property to have when dealing with money.)

I don't think that this rule is available in the standard API, although it isn't hard to code it up.

Comment: The rule is very much available in the standard API - twice, actually: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_HALF_EVEN and http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_EVEN

Comment: Am I correct that the "round half to even" rule is what I am using in the example above and can simply stick with the above code to do "banker's rounding"?

Comment: @Michael - Thanks. I should have dug through the docs a little deeper.

Answer (score 2):

You're already using `BigDecimal` for the rounding, you're already using a rounding mode that is well-suited for financial applications unless there are specific requirements or regulations that proscribe a different one.

The only thing you absolutely MUST do is take the last step and use `BigDecimal` to represent the money values throughout your application. That's exactly what it's for, and it's much better suited to that task than `double` since it can represent decimal fractions exactly as expected.