# Rounding to 2 decimal places

Tags: java, floating-point

```
(Math.round(doubleValue*100))/100.0
```

Is there a better way to round decimals to 2 decimal places?

Comment: Define better?  What do you think is wrong with that code?

Comment: you mean 1000 to change in 1 or 10.123456 to 10.12?

Comment: Similar question, Rounding for money, at http://stackoverflow.com/q/5904032/509840.

Comment: @Mikola it looks bad. @Ovais the latter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Round a double to 2 significant figures after decimal point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-significant-figures-after-decimal-point)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DecimalFormat format=new DecimalFormat("#.##");
System.out.println(format.format(doubleValue));
```

Comment: You don't need to import anything from `java.lang`.

Comment: Do note: this does not round numbers.  It just displays strings that have been formatted to a certain precision.  The answer from John Skeet is the appropriate way to round to an explicit number of decimals without the juggling act of multiply-round-divide by OP.

Answer (score 7):

If you're interested in decimal places and therefore precise decimal values, you should typically be using [`java.math.BigDecimal`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) to start with. You can then use `Decimal.round` or `Decimal.setScale` to round according to your exact needs.